# How do I get next row id with same group_id value

Tags: mysql

I have below table in mysql:

```
+-----+------------+------------+  
| id  | group_id   |    other   |  
+-----+------------+------------+  
| 5   |     21     |   ......   |  
| 6   |     21     |   ......   |  
| 7   |     23     |   ......   |  
| 8   |     23     |   ......   |  
| 9   |     21     |   ......   | 
| 10  |     21     |   ......   | 
+-----+------------+------------+
```

I select row with id **6** and show row's data in single page
I want to add a button in single page that have next row id with same group_id of this single page's row. means select id **9** row
How can I do this with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the next row with `id` greater than current one or an empty result if `group_id` is exhausted.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE group_id = 21 -- should be provided  
   AND id > 6        -- ID of the current row should be placed
 ORDER BY id ASC
 LIMIT 1
;
```